# Get information from "inspector" on a web page

Tags: web, inspector

A really noob web programmer here!
So I need to build a program that, as I give it a link it inspect the page (like the right click and "inspect element" option that we have in Firefox) and get the infromation from it exported. I wanna be able to filter what kind of information that I am having and to put them all together in a hash or somethink like this.

Does anyone have a tip? What language should I go for? There is any plugin or lib that already does that? I just want a direction so I can get started with this project! Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like JavaScript's [**document.getElementById()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)? Or are you looking to scrape the contents of a website you don't own?

Comment: The second option!

Here in Brazil we have a site that lists all stores that have a specific card from Magic the Gathering. I wanna make a program so I can plan the best combination of stores so I can get the smallest cost at the purchase multiple cards from multiple places(including delivery fees).